# Using facebook standard object types within custom stories

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am interested to use a facebook standard object type defined in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type in my custom action or as a property of a custom object but facebook does not offer much types when creating a property: [image: Facebook limited types]

Is it possible to extend the types in properties to any of the facebook types.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that creating new stories, you can access all the standard Facebook types. So my conclusion is that you can create stories with FB types but you cannot add these types as properties to actions or objects. These types must be the main type (the noun) of the action.

Wonder why Facebook designed it this way and why they do not clearly document their design and goals so we understand and fit properly into their great platform.

Answer (score 0):

Another step: I can even use a FB type as a property and not juste as a noun (what I've called a main object type). I just add another story using the FB type as a noun and this type become available in the other object types as a property. Cumbersome, but working. 
Facebook, please react.